# Composer Install Giving a Ton of Errors

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, homestead, laravel-artisan

I am trying to run `composer install` and I am getting a ton of errors. What do they mean?

```js
composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.28
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.27
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.26
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.25
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.24
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.23
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.22
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.21
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.20
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.19
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.18
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.17
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.16
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.15
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.14
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.13
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.12
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.11
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.10
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.9
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.8
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.3
    - Installation request for davibennun/laravel-push-notification dev-master -> satisfiable by davibennun/laravel-push-notification[dev-master].
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.1
    - davibennun/laravel-push-notification dev-master requires illuminate/support 4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.10, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7, v4.0.8, v4.0.9, v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.13, v4.1.14, v4.1.15, v4.1.16, v4.1.17, v4.1.18, v4.1.19, v4.1.2, v4.1.20, v4.1.21, v4.1.22, v4.1.23, v4.1.24, v4.1.25, v4.1.26, v4.1.27, v4.1.28, v4.1.29, v4.1.3, v4.1.30, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9, v4.2.1, v4.2.12, v4.2.16, v4.2.17, v4.2.2, v4.2.3, v4.2.4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9].
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.0.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.0.10|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.0.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.0.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.0.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.0.5|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.0.6|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.0.7|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.0.8|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.0.9|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.10|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.11|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.12|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.13|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.14|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.15|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.16|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.17|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.18|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.19|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.20|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.21|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.22|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.23|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.24|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.25|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.26|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.27|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.29|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.30|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.5|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.6|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.7|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.8|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.9|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.12|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.16|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.17|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.5|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.6|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.7|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.8|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.9|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 5.5.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.5.0, v5.5.1, v5.5.10, v5.5.11, v5.5.12, v5.5.13, v5.5.14, v5.5.15, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.18, v5.5.19, v5.5.2, v5.5.20, v5.5.21, v5.5.22, v5.5.23, v5.5.24, v5.5.25, v5.5.26, v5.5.27, v5.5.28, v5.5.3, v5.5.4, v5.5.5, v5.5.6, v5.5.7, v5.5.8, v5.5.9].
```

And here is my `composer.json` file:

```js
{
 "name": "laravel/laravel",
 "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
 "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
 "license": "MIT",
 "type": "project",
 "require": {
  "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit" : "6.0.*",
    "doctrine/dbal": "~2.3",
    "aws/aws-sdk-php": "2.*",
    "zizaco/entrust": "1.2.*@dev",
    "mandrill/mandrill": "1.0.54",
    "curl/curl": "1.2.0",
    "artdarek/oauth-4-laravel": "1.0.5",
    "abraham/twitteroauth": "0.7.2",
    "davibennun/laravel-push-notification": "dev-master",
    "stripe/stripe-php": "4.4.*",
        "intervention/image": "2.1.3",
        "mockery/mockery" : "0.9.4",
        "nesbot/carbon" : "1.*",
        "sendgrid/sendgrid" : "4.0.*",
        "twilio/sdk" : "5.8.0",
  "php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg": "^0.6.1",
        "sinergi/browser-detector" : "6.1.2",
        "google/apiclient" : "2.*",
  "sentry/sentry-laravel": "^0.7.0",
        "maatwebsite/excel" : "1.3.10",
  "lizhibin/php-mcrypt": "dev-master"
 },
    "require-dev" : {
        "phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor": "2.*"
    },
 "autoload": {
  "classmap": [
   "app/commands",
   "app/controllers",
   "app/models",
   "app/database/migrations",
   "app/database/seeds",
   "app/tests/TestCase.php",
     "app/helpers",
            "app/jobs"
  ]
 },
 "scripts": {
  "post-install-cmd": [
   "php artisan clear-compiled",
   "php artisan optimize"
  ],
  "post-update-cmd": [
   "php artisan clear-compiled",
   "php artisan optimize"
  ],
  "post-create-project-cmd": [
   "php artisan key:generate"
  ]
 },
 "config": {
  "preferred-install": "dist"
 },
 "minimum-stability": "stable"
}
```

`php -v` returns:

`PHP 7.1.12-3+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Dec 14 2017 15:37:13) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.1.12-3+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
    with blackfire v1.18.0~linux-x64-non_zts71, https://blackfire.io, by SensioLabs`

Can someone help me figure out what any of this means? I have done some research and I have been stuck with these errors.

I am running my Laravel project in Homestead/Vagrant

Comment: You can test the results of a require failure by using the [prohibits command](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#prohibits-why-not-).  e.g. `php composer.phar why-not laravel/framework v5.5.28` In effect it looks like `davibennun/laravel-push-notification dev-master`  has a requirement for `illuminate/support 4.*` to which laravel matches the version number of its dependencies with the version you install. There is a pull request for laravel 5 support https://github.com/davibennun/laravel-push-notification/pull/187

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're pulling in the wrong version of the `davibennun/laravel-push-notification` package - looks like your composer.json file references `"davibennun/laravel-push-notification": "dev-master"` however I believe you require `"davibennun/laravel-push-notification": "dev-laravel5"` for Laravel 5.

See here https://github.com/davibennun/laravel-push-notification.